# Excel calculations based on INDEX match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to calculate the time differences from column A for each colored segment next to the corresponding action in column E.

I have an Index created to generate all the timestamps related to rows with "Begin"
Column F is a simple representation of what I would like to achieve.

```
INDEX($A$2:$D$34,SMALL(IF($C:$C=$H$2,ROW($C:$C)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)
```

This provides an array of objects from Column A where Column C matches Begin.
I'm not sure if this helps.

This example features Greg but I also have a lot of other "Sales People".
Regardless of the number of sales people I still want the results the same.

All objects between the rows with Begin should calculate based Index iterated.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Begin marker in column C, you may use this to calculate column E as:

```
=IF(C2="Begin","",(A2-A1)+IF(E1="",0,E1))
```

Enter this formula in E2 and then fill down. By formatting column E with the Time format, this gives the difference in column E:

[image]

Comment: From the work I've done with your code it would seem I would need to hard code these locations. I have about 2500 lines in the sheet.
If there is additional logic involved maybe I'm not picking it up?

Comment: @Steve have you perhaps not used relative references and Fill in Excel? When you select a cell and then "Fill Down", Excel adjusts the references so they all end up correct relative to the rows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6 So you only have to type the formula once, into E2.

Comment: I found this worked: 
Using relative references:

=$A38-INDEX($A$2:$A38,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($C$2:$C38)*($H$2=$C$2:$C38))-1))

starting from $E2 and copying down the line it gives the closest "Begin" calculation to the current "Greg" line. All "Begin" lines are 00:00:00

Comment: @Steve sounds like the same result then. So I'm not sure why you're using a more complicated formula? Just paste my formula in E2 and do the same. BTW you mention you're getting "00:00:00" but my formula already includes an IF statement to show the empty cells instead of "00:00:00". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
=$A38-INDEX($A$2:$A38,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($C$2:$C38)*($H$2=$C$2:$C38))-1))
```

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ys3p.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ys3p.png